# To send a task does not work occasionally use celery + rabbitmq

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I made a post website use flask. When users post I use celery + rabbitmq inform its friends.But, the celery does not work occasionally, well most of the time it is normal.

Details are as follows.

This is my celery config:

```
from celery import Celery
# from celery.schedules import crontab
from kombu import Queue, Exchange
from nowdo.config import setting
# from datetime import timedelta


class BaseConfig(object):
    CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True
    CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Shanghai'
    CELERY_QUEUES = (
        Queue('nowdo_default', Exchange('nowdo_default'),  routing_key='nowdo_default'),
        Queue('nowdo_file_extract', Exchange('nowdo_file_extract'), routing_key='nowdo.file.extract'),
        Queue('nowdo_send_mail', Exchange("nowdo_send_mail"), routing_key='nowdo.sendmail'),
        Queue('nowdo_create_trend_showed', Exchange('nowdo_create_trend_showed'),
          routing_key='nowdo.trend_showed.create'),
        Queue('nowdo_refresh_some_trend_showed_by_user', Exchange('nowdo_refresh_some_trend_showed_by_user'),
          routing_key='nowdo.trend_showed.refresh_some_by_user'),
        Queue('nowdo_create_some_trend_showed_by_trend', Exchange('nowdo_create_some_trend_showed_by_trend'),
          routing_key='nowdo.trend_showed.create_some_by_trend'),
        Queue('nowdo_pull_web_file', Exchange('nowdo_pull_web_file'),
          routing_key='nowdo.pull.web_file'),
        Queue('nowdo_delete_some_trend_showed', Exchange('nowdo_delete_some_trend_showed'),
          routing_key='nowdo.trend_showed.delete_some_trend_showed'),
        Queue('nowdo_send_group_notice', Exchange('nowdo_send_group_notice'),
          routing_key='nowdo.notice.send_group_notice'),
        Queue('nowdo_send_group_new_task_notice', Exchange('nowdo_send_group_new_task_notice'),
          routing_key='nowdo.notice.send_group_new_task_notice'),
        Queue('nowdo_send_some_group_new_task_notice', Exchange('nowdo_send_some_group_new_task_notice'),
          routing_key='nowdo.notice.send_some_group_new_task_notice'),
    # not use
        Queue('nowdo_create_text_result_cache', Exchange('nowdo_create_text_result_cache'),
          routing_key='nowdo.task_cache.create_text_result_cache'),
)

CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY = "nowdo_default"
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'nowdo_default'
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE = "nowdo_default"
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE = "direct"

CELERY_ROUTES = {
    "nowdo.tasks.translate.extract_worker": {
        "routing_key": "nowdo.file.extract",
        "queue": "nowdo_file_extract",
    },
    "nowdo.utils.mail.send_mail": {
        "queue": "nowdo_send_mail",
        "routing_key": "nowdo.sendmail",
    },
    "nowdo.tasks.trend_showed.create_trend_showed_worker": {
        "routing_key": "nowdo.trend_showed.create",
        "queue": "nowdo_create_trend_showed",
    },
    "nowdo.tasks.trend_showed.refresh_some_trend_showed_by_user_worker": {
        "routing_key": "nowdo.trend_showed.refresh_some_by_user",
        "queue": "nowdo_refresh_some_trend_showed_by_user",
    },
    "nowdo.tasks.trend_showed.create_some_trend_showed_by_trend_worker": {
        "routing_key": "nowdo.trend_showed.create_some_by_trend",
        "queue": "nowdo_create_some_trend_showed_by_trend",
    },
    "nowdo.tasks.pull_web_file.pull_web_file_worker": {
        "routing_key": "nowdo.pull.web_file",
        "queue": "nowdo_pull_web_file",
    },
    "nowdo.tasks.trend_showed.delete_some_trend_showed_worker": {
        "routing_key": "nowdo.trend_showed.delete_some_trend_showed",
        "queue": "nowdo_delete_some_trend_showed",
    },
    "nowdo.tasks.notice.send_group_notice_worker": {
        "routing_key": "nowdo.notice.send_group_notice",
        "queue": "nowdo_send_group_notice",
    },
    "nowdo.tasks.notice.send_group_new_task_notice_worker": {
        "routing_key": "nowdo.notice.send_group_new_task_notice",
        "queue": "nowdo_send_group_new_task_notice",
    },
    "nowdo.tasks.notice.send_some_group_new_task_notice_worker": {
        "routing_key": "nowdo.notice.send_some_group_new_task_notice",
        "queue": "nowdo_send_some_group_new_task_notice",
    },
    # not use
    "nowdo.tasks.task_cache.create_text_result_cache": {
        "routing_key": "nowdo.task_cache.create_text_result_cache",
        "queue": "nowdo_create_text_result_cache",
    },
}

CELERY_IMPORTS = (
    'nowdo.tasks.pull_web_file',
    'nowdo.tasks.translate',
    'nowdo.tasks.trend_showed',
    'nowdo.tasks.task_cache',
    'nowdo.utils.mail',
    'nowdo.tasks.notice',
)

#: Email settings
CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS = True
ADMINS = (
    ('zouyingjun', 'zouyingjun@xingcloud.com'),
    ('fuluheng', 'fuluheng@xingcloud.com'),
    ('wangweiwei', 'wangweiwei@xingcloud.com')
)
SERVER_EMAIL = 'DNFS stat info<xcmonitor01@163.com>'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.163.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xcmonitor01@163.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xingcloud'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_TIMEOUT = 10
BROKER_URL = setting.BROKER_URL

celery = Celery()
celery.config_from_object(BaseConfig)
```

This is my tasks:

```
import traceback
import time
from nowdo.config.celeryconfig import celery
from nowdo.controls.group import GroupUserRel
from nowdo.controls.notice import Notice
from nowdo.controls.session import session_cm
from nowdo.utils.nowdo_logger import nowdo_celery_logger as logger


@celery.task(ignore_result=True)
def send_group_notice_worker(sender_id, receiver_id_list, group_notice_id):
    try:
        with session_cm() as db_session:
            Notice.send_to_many(db_session, Notice.NOTICE_TYPE_GROUP_NOTICE, sender_id,
                                receiver_id_list, group_notice_id)
    except:
        logger.error(traceback.format_exc())


@celery.task(ignore_result=True, default_retry_delay=5, max_retries=10)
def send_group_new_task_notice_worker(sender_id, group_id, task_id):
    a = time.time()
    with session_cm() as db_session:
        b = time.time()

        user_ids = db_session.query(GroupUserRel.user_id).filter(GroupUserRel.group_id == group_id)\
            .filter(GroupUserRel.user_id != sender_id).all()
        c = time.time()
        user_id_list = [u[0] for u in user_ids]
        d = time.time()
        size = len(user_id_list)
        block_len = 20
        e = time.time()
        user_id_lists = [user_id_list[i:i+block_len] for i in range(0, size, block_len)]
        f = time.time()
        for u in user_id_lists:
            celery.send_task("nowdo.tasks.notice.send_some_group_new_task_notice_worker", [sender_id, u, task_id])
            # send_some_group_new_task_notice_worker(sender_id, u, task_id)
        g = time.time()
        load_session, count_user_ids, get_id_list, defined_variable, get_id_lists, send_every_task = b - a, c - b, d - c, e - d, f - e, g - f
        if load_session > 10:
            logger.warn('load_session problem')
            # print 'load_session problem'
        if count_user_ids > 10:
            logger.warn('count_user_ids problem')
            # print 'count_user_ids problem'
        if get_id_list > 10:
            logger.warn('get_id_list problem')
            # print 'get_id_list problem'
        if defined_variable > 10:
            logger.warn('defined_variable problem')
            # print 'defined_variable problem'
        if get_id_lists > 10:
            logger.warn('get_id_lists problem')
            # print 'get_id_lists problem'
        if send_every_task > 10:
            logger.warn('send_every_task problem')
            # print 'send_every_task problem'


@celery.task(ignore_result=True, default_retry_delay=5, max_retries=10)
def send_some_group_new_task_notice_worker(sender_id, user_id_list, task_id):
    with session_cm() as db_session:
        a = time.time()
        Notice.send_to_many(db_session, Notice.NOTICE_TYPE_CREATE_GROUP_TASK,
                            sender_id, user_id_list, task_id)
        if time.time() - a > 10:
            logger.warn('send_to_many problem')
            # print 'send_to_many problem'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

This is part of the code;
this is handle in views:

```
@task_bp.route('/create_task', methods=['POST'])
@ajax_login_required()
@talk_forbidden_check
def create_task():
            # this is create a task
            ......
            t1_1 = time.time()
            if group_id:
                group = db_session.query(Group).filter(Group.id == group_id).first()
            else:
                group = None
            t1_2 = time.time()
            new_task, new_trends = CrowdSourceTask.create_crowd_source_task(
                db_session,
                current_user,
                task_name,
                src_lang,
                status,
                tags,
                group=group,
                content=task_content,
                max_translate_count=50,
            )

            t1_3 = time.time()
            ......
            res.update({
                "status": "create",
                "data": FormattedTrends.get_formatted_trends_list([new_trends], current_user)[0]
            })
            t2_1, t2_2, t2_3, t2_4, t2_5 = t1_2 - t1_1, t1_3 - t1_2, t1_4 - t1_3, t1_5 - t1_4, time.time() - t1_5
            if t2_1 > 10:
                current_app.logger.error("group handle problem")

            if t2_2 > 10:
                current_app.logger.error("create_crowd_source_task handle problem")

            if t2_3 > 10:
                current_app.logger.error("add score handle problem")

            if t2_4 > 10:
                current_app.logger.error("remove_draft handle problem")

            if t2_5 > 10:
                current_app.logger.error("get_formatted_trends_list handle problem")

            return jsonify(res)
```

this is handle in controls:

```
    @classmethod
    def create_crowd_source_task(cls, session, current_user, name, src_lang, status, tags_str,
                             description=None,
                             group=None,
                             content=None,
                             uploaded_file=None,
                             # glossary_table_id=None,
                             max_translate_count=100,
                             start_date=None, end_date=None,
                             reserved_words=None,
                             ):
        t3_1 = time.time()
        ......
        t3_5 = time.time()
        # after comit
        if group:
            celery.send_task('nowdo.tasks.notice.send_group_new_task_notice_worker',
                             [current_user.id, group.id, crowd_task.id])
            # from nowdo.tasks.notice import send_group_new_task_notice_worker
            # send_group_new_task_notice_worker(current_user.id, group.id, crowd_task.id)
        t3_6 = time.time()
        if status:
            crowd_task.active(src_lang)
        t3_7 = time.time()
        group_id = group.id if group else None


        # crowd_task.init_empty_progress()

        trends = Trends.add_trends(current_user, TREND_ACTION_CREATE, TREND_TARGET_TYPE_TASK, crowd_task, group_id)

        t4_1, t4_2, t4_3, t4_4, t4_5, t4_6, t4_7 = t3_2 - t3_1, t3_3 - t3_2, t3_4 - t3_3, t3_5 - t3_4, t3_6 - t3_5,\
            t3_7 - t3_6, time.time() - t3_7

        if t4_1 > 10:
            logger.warn("create_orig_file handle problem")
            # print "create_orig_file handle problem"

        if t4_2 > 10:
            logger.warn("CrowdSourceTaskContent handle problem")
            # print "CrowdSourceTaskContent handle problem"

        if t4_3 > 10:
            logger.warn("update_tags handle problem")
            # print "update_tags handle problem"

        if t4_4 > 10:
            logger.warn("CrowdSourceTaskTagRel handle problem")
            # print "CrowdSourceTaskTagRel handle problem"

        if t4_5 > 10:
            logger.warn("send_task handle problem")
            # print "send_task handle problem"

        if t4_6 > 10:
            logger.warn("crowd_task.active handle problem")
            # print "crowd_task.active handle problem"

        if t4_7 > 10:
            logger.warn("add_trends handle problem")
            # print "add_trends handle problem"

        return crowd_task, trends
```

This is my log:
[image] 
I found it that the code

```
celery.send_task('nowdo.tasks.notice.send_group_new_task_notice_worker',
                                 [current_user.id, group.id, crowd_task.id])
```

done not work so that nginx timeout.

I hope my description is accurate, please help me.

Comment: please try to edit the code you have posted so that only the most relevant sections are included - this is a lot of reading

Comment: is the problem that `celery.send_task()` taking a very long time?

Comment: Yes, it looks like there has been no work according to my log, because here to stay too long time that like you said. But it is so  occasionally. Can you help me ?